# Is it possible to invert normal maps in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a normal map which is 'looking in a wrong direction' and I would like to get exactly opposite effect that this map gives in my Cycles render. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Bump map

For a bump map you can just drop in a *invert node* between the bump image and the *bump* node.

---

### Normal map

For a normal map you can separate the RGB color channels and invert just the red and the green channels. Like in the image below.
<sub>click image for full size</sub>
[image: nodes]

Comment: More general solution is presented at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/how-to-weaken-or-strengthen-a-normal-map-texture