# Why do my normal maps look like trash?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, normal-map

[image]

(in blender Cycles) I have created a Sculpt of a head with dynamic Typology, created a retypology. Uv unwrapped the low typology (no mirror modifiers). I then created a 2048 by 2048 new image to bake the normals to. I baked the image and here are my settings[image] everything is smoothed with the generic smooth vertices toggle. I am sure that the normal maps should have better results than this from what i see other people getting on youtube I have put quite a bit of time into walking around in circles on the internet and in blender so help at this point would be very welcome.there is also a weird cuttle fish effect on the faces skin I dont know if that is just a product of the pixels but to me it looks obvious and ugly.
I just created this account to ask this question so i am yet to figure out how to post my blend file but hopefully i can solve that one.

Comment: your normal map appears to be indenting instead of bumping

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13648/is-it-possible-to-invert-normal-maps-in-cycles

Comment: Could you try connecting the _Normal_ output of the normal map to the _Normal_ input of the shader, instead of to the _Displacement_ socket of the material output?

Comment: I don't think normal maps are intended for displacement inputs. As Duane said, you should attach it to the Normal input of the shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if it isn't already, set your normal map texture to "non-color data." It doesn't work properly if it is set to color data.

If attaching the normal output to the normal input of the diffuse shader doesn't work, this node setup (courtesy of @david) will invert the normal map.

[image: Invert normal map]

Comment: thanks guys for the replies. I connected the normal map to the normal input of the defuse shader. This fixed my ugly shading problem. for anyone else who had this problem, it is important that you also change the image texture to non colour data otherwise it turns your mesh darker and may have you scratching your head for an extra 15 mins or so.